# Hide or display text in Microsoft Word VBA based on data read from a MS access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm looking to read in data from a Microsoft access database, particularly, a few yes and no fields and use conditionals to hide or display certain questions within a Microsoft word template based on those fields. Is there any way that I can go about accomplishing this? are there any free online resources that anyone can point me towards? thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, with enough code. Lots of examples about programming Word and Access merging. Whether the code is behind Access or Word, it won't be simple. Do you really need Word? Why not reports in Access? Question is really too broad.

Comment: For a start, review http://kallal.ca/wordmerge/index.html